# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have trained and saved a model :

```
import numpy as np

# load the dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt("modiftrain.csv", delimiter=";")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X_train = dataset[:,0:5]
Y_train = dataset[:,5]

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

# create Gaussian Naive Bayes model object and train it with the data
nb_model = GaussianNB()

nb_model.fit(X_train, Y_train.ravel())

# predict values using the training data
nb_predict_train = nb_model.predict(X_train)

# import the performance metrics library
from sklearn import metrics

# Accuracy
print("Accuracy: {0:.4f}".format(metrics.accuracy_score(Y_train, nb_predict_train)))
print()

# import the lib to load / Save the model
from sklearn.externals import joblib  

# Save the model
joblib.dump(nb_predict_train, "trained-model.pkl")
```

Then, i'm loading the model and try to make predictions on a new dataset :

```
# import the lib to load / Save the model
from sklearn.externals import joblib  

import numpy as np 

# Load the model
nb_predict_train = joblib.load("trained-model.pkl")

# load the test dataset
df_predict = np.loadtxt("modiftest.csv", delimiter=";")

X_train = df_predict

nb_predict_train.predict(X_train)

print(X_train)
```

Here comes the error :

```
  File "predict01.py", line 14, in <module>
    nb_predict_train.predict(X_train)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to pickle the predictions but rather the fit.

Change `joblib.dump(nb_predict_train, "trained-model.pkl")` to `joblib.dump(nb_model, "trained-model.pkl")`

Comment: Error corrected !
I have one more question, if I want to print my predicted values, what shall I write ?  print(X_train) does not seems to give me the rightout put

Comment: X_train is still your loaded dataset so I imagine you received a matrix.  If you want to print your predictions try `pred = nb_predict_train.predict(X_train)` then `print(pred)`

Comment: Oh ! Yes ! Looks like the right output now. Thx

Comment: Shall I push my luck ? And ask for a bit more help ?
Now that I have this beautiful array, how can I write it in a csv file, in the column number 6 ?

Comment: I added that piece of code :

`import csv
csvfile = "toto.csv"

with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in pred:
        writer.writerow([val])`

and it wrote the csv file. But I don't know how to write it in the column number 6 instead of in the first one....

Comment: Try this `data = np.loadtext(filename)` and then after you do your prediction concat the two arrays by `concat_array = np.c_[data,pred]`  Finally you have `np.savetxt(outputfilename,concat_array)`.  On a related note, you should spend time figure out how to do this in base python.  It isn't too hard and a useful exercise.